# Unable to detect Seeedstudio Bluetooth Shield

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I have a problem regarding Seeedstudio Bluetooth shield http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/Bluetooth-Shield-p-866.html

I can't detect its presence by any other devices.

The code I uploaded to Arduino is a standard example for slave device from the library:

```
/* Upload this sketch into Seeeduino and press reset*/

#include <SoftwareSerial.h>   //Software Serial Port
#define RxD 6
#define TxD 7

#define DEBUG_ENABLED  1

SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD,TxD);

void setup() 
{ 
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(RxD, INPUT);
    pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
    setupBlueToothConnection(); 
} 

void loop() 
{ 
    char recvChar;
    while(1)
    {
        if(blueToothSerial.available()){//check if there's any data sent from the remote bluetooth shield
            recvChar = blueToothSerial.read();
            Serial.print(recvChar);
        }
        if(Serial.available()){//check if there's any data sent from the local serial terminal, you can add the other applications here
            recvChar  = Serial.read();
            blueToothSerial.print(recvChar);
        }
    }
} 

void setupBlueToothConnection()
{
    blueToothSerial.begin(38400); //Set BluetoothBee BaudRate to default baud rate 38400
    blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n"); //set the bluetooth work in slave mode
    blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STNA=SeeedBTSlave\r\n"); //set the bluetooth name as "SeeedBTSlave"
    blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n"); // Permit Paired device to connect me
    blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n"); // Auto-connection should be forbidden here
    delay(2000); // This delay is required.
    blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n"); //make the slave bluetooth inquirable 
    Serial.println("The slave bluetooth is inquirable!");
    delay(2000); // This delay is required.
    blueToothSerial.flush();
}
```

I've uploaded it to Arduino UNO, connected the shield and... Nothing.

LED marked as `D1` is blinking green, and `D2` is switched off. The device is not detected by none of the three devices I've tried (two computers and a smartphone).

By "not detected" I mean "`hcitool` returns nothing and OS based search for Bluetooth devices reports nothing". All three devices can detect each other without any problems.

I tried to connect it to other UNO board (in case the first one was damaged), but the result is the same. 
I thought that the shield is somehow at fault, so I had it replaced by a new one - but the results are still the same.

Summing up:

- 3 extrnal devices
- 2 Arduinos
- 2 shields

Tested in all possible combinations, and still  no success.

The device is powered up, because when I set it to send it's status to `A1` analog port I always read `0` instead of a random value.

The only logical conclusion is that there is something wrong with the code above, but every google search I've made pointed me exactly to that file. It's from official wiki and in every example I've found. I've tried to contact Seeedstudio about it, but they didn't have anything of value to add ("try rebooting until it works").

Has anyone had similar problem, or has any advice what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem on my own.

Two steps were required:

First of all I had to use hardware serial port (ports 0 and 1 on Arduino UNO), because for some reason SoftwareSerial doesn't work well with this shield.

Then I had to battery as power supply, since serial communication via ports 0 and 1 has lower priority than USB serial.

The disadvantage of this solution is that you lose USB communication with your PC, but fortunately I didn't need it.

EDIT: To avoid any confusion, here is an example of the code which worked for me:

```
void setup() 
{ 
  setupBlueToothConnection(); 
  Serial.flush();
} 

void loop() 
{ 
  for (char i = 0; i <= 254; i++)
  {
    Serial.print(i);
    delay(1000);
  }  

} 

void setupBlueToothConnection()
{
  Serial.begin(38400); //Set BluetoothBee BaudRate to default baud rate 38400
  Serial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n"); //set the bluetooth work in slave mode
  Serial.print("\r\n+STNA=SeeedBTSlave\r\n"); //set the bluetooth name as "SeeedBTSlave"
  Serial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n"); // Permit Paired device to connect me
  Serial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n"); // Auto-connection should be forbidden here
  delay(2000); // This delay is required.
  Serial.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n"); //make the slave bluetooth inquirable 
  //Serial.println("The slave bluetooth is inquirable!");
  delay(2000); // This delay is required.
  Serial.flush();      
}
```

Please note that the modem sends answers to some of the commands, you should clean `Serial` buffer before reading from it.

Also, the jumpers on the shield should be connected like this: BT_TX to pin 0 and BT_RX to pin 1.

Comment: And what is your problem? How does your shield behave? Maybe I can help.

Comment: No matter what I do I never get data in or out. None of the commands I send work. It just started happening. I assumed it was my fault until I found this thread: http://www.seeedstudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=4444&start=10
Others apparently have experienced this situation: it was working fine. Turned it on one day, never goes back to discoverable. No paired devices around. Pins and jumpers set properly. Nothing.

Comment: If it was working, and suddenly it stopped, then maybe it is damaged? Seeedstudio's products aren't exactly durable... On your shield is a switch "PIO[1]". Set it to "A1" state, it will provide a signal to A1 analog pin. Connect some (10 if posible) LEDs to digital ports and use them to display result of reading A1 (remember, you can't use USB serial to get it!). If it's always zero, then there is still hope, because the device is reporting something and you simply need someone wiser than me to help you. If it's random - the shield is dead.

Comment: Oh, and by the way - what are LEDs D1 and D2 doing?

Comment: I can confirm switching from softwareserial to hardware ports 0/1 also fixed this for me, even though using softwareserial and hardware ports at the same time was working in the past (weird).  @oliverseal you might like to check the code in this post here http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=128973.0 and make sure you don't have any wires connecting to tx/rx pins on the bee if you are using hardware serial comms.